# Assigning pattern information to pictures (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, design-patterns, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I'm new to the iOS development world and I'm making a small (potentially addictive) game. I know Python and HTML/CSS so I will be able to cope with computer terms, but it would be great if you would be able to explain any answers.

In my game, a pattern flashes on the screen for a small amount of time, let's say it is 'arrow left, arrow right, arrow left' (in the form of a picture). Then the user has to replicate the pattern (in the right order) in order to boost forward. I am going to use UIGestureRecogniser to call the boost function with the 'correct' pattern. The next step in my programming is assigning 'paths' to pictures. The recogniser will test if user input is equal to the pattern shown, but I need a way for the computer to see if the pattern shown is inputted by the user (sorry if it's confusing). In essence, what would be the most effective way of having the computer recognise if the pattern given by the user is similar to the one that is shown on screen.

Thank you in advance,

Will

Comment: what pattern is it ..any particular shape? give an example of a pattern

Comment: @turbo Well the pattern could be something like 'arrow left, arrow right, arrow left' or 'arrow down, arrow right, arrow up'. Of course I mean 'arrow pointing up' (it's in picture form).

Comment: Do you feel that you can at least generate the input pattern from the `UIGestureRecogniser`? In other words, that you can properly detect left, right, up, and down?

Comment: @MobileBen Of course, any help you can give me is greatly appreciated. The answer given by Radwa Ebrahim is good, but I would like the code to 'be personalised' to the examples that I gave in the first comment of that question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alrighty, so I actually misread the first time and updated this. Previously I had indicated how to solve for finding which pattern would match a sequence, if any. You already know the sequence, which makes it way easier!

Lets make a few assumptions:

-We are using the enum

```
enum PatternType: Int {
    case Left = 0, Right, Up, Down
}
```

Note I know Radwa Ebrahim mentioned an enum and defined it as `ShapeType`. However, you really sound like you are doing "pattern recognition". Hence `ShapeType` does not clearly define what the enum is. It should actually probably be `PatternDirection` or even `GestureDirection`.

-You already have the ability read in the gestures properly. The results are provided in an `Array<PatternType>`.

-You have a defined array of arrays which represent the patterns to match. This is `Array<Array<PatternType>>`. In other words, you now what you're trying to match up against.

-You already now how to map your images to each direction in the enum.

-You know the sequence you are matching against.

So let's look at the brute force approach. The brute force approach is to store the pattern sequences like this (just an example):

```
let patternSequences:[[PatternType]] = [
    [ .Left, .Left, .Left ], // This is sequence 0
    [ .Right, .Right, .Right], // This is sequence 1
    [ .Left, .Right, .Right, .Up ] // This is sequence 2
    // Add more of your sequences here, each line is a sequence to match against
    // as well as the pattern you will show on screen
    [ .Down, .Up, .Left, .Down, .Up ] // Later on this, could be sequence 35
]
```

More slick would be loading this from JSON or a plist, but that exercise is left up to you.

Let's say you have the results:

```
var results:[PatternType] = [ .Left, .Right, .Right, .Up ]
```

Your matching can be done with `==` (no overloading needed for this setup, since we are an array of `PatternType`, which is already Equatable since the enum contains no associated data)

So calling this would be something like

```
// After you have retrieved the input
if patternSequences[currentSequence] == results {
    // Indicate success
} else {
   // Indicate failure
}
```

Where `currentSequence` is the currentSequence you just got from the user.

Comment: Thank you for spending so much time on this. Just a couple of things it would be nice to clear up before I award the bounty. 1) Your first let statement, the three different 'examples' - do they count as three patterns? Would it be possible to add more, and access them by doing something like PatternType[35]. I already have a function that creates five random numbers, so could I do PatternType[rand]? Contrary to your for and ifs, would it be easier to do 'if PatternType[35] = userinput'? PS. Would I store the user's input in a file, and then match, or something else? Thank you so much

Comment: Updated the answer. I had misread it at first. You don't need to find it. To answer your questions, yes, those are 3 patterns (think of them as pattern sequences, or just sequence to help make the names easier to distinguish). You can add more and you can access them with something like `patternSequences[35]`. You cannot use `PatternType[35]` because PatternType is a data type. I also would not hardcode values, but rather use something like `currentSequence` to indicate the index. And you also need to bounds check to make sure `currentSequence` is within the array's bounds.

Comment: Testing is something like `patternSequences[currentSequence] == results`. Where results is from your program. There is no need to save it to a file. You are going to need to figure out how to work out that data flow from user input to calling the code that will compare and then show the results, as it is a little harder to explain that here.

Comment: Just out of interest, why do you need Left = 0? (the =0 part)? Thanks. Bounty awarded.

Comment: Also, with the .Lefts and things I get the error 'AnyObject.Protocol does not have a member named 'Left''.

Comment: I did `Left = 0`, or more precisely `enum PatternType : Int` so that you can work more easily with a data file like JSON or plist. For those files, `Left` has no meaning. By making the enum have a raw type of on Int, you can then easily map Int values into PatternType. You also could have used a `String` instead and used the actual string `"Left"` or `"left"` to represent left.

Comment: As far as the `.Left`. That only works when the enum values can be inferred. Else you need to explicitly list it as `PatternType.Left`. I would recommend you read about enums (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html). Getting used to how to find this info in the Apple docs will go a long way in helping you figure out these things.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have an object called `Pattern` that contains an array of objects called `Shape`. Each `Shape` object have a property called `type` that can be an enum and looks like the following:

```
enum ShapeType {
    case ArrowLeft
    case ArrowRight
    case ArrowUp
    case ArrowDown
}
```

Every time you generate a pattern to display, you save it in a `Pattern` object let's call it "currentPattern", then take the user input into anther `Pattern` object and call it "userPattern".

Pattern and Shape classes should provide the `==` operator overloading to look like the following:

in Shape

```
func == (left: Shape, right: Shape) -> Bool {
  return left.type == right.type
}
```

in Pattern

```
func == (left: Pattern, right: Pattern) -> Bool {
  return left.shapesArray == right.shapesArray
}
```

This way in your function that will compare the patterns (like either when he tap Done, or when the count of the input is reached the required count) , all you need to do is

```
if currentPattern == userPattern {
   // it's correct,proceed to the next step
}else {
   // show a pretty losing message
}
```

Hint that the above code is in Swift, if you are using Objective-C you will need to override `isEqual` instead of the `==` operator.

Comment: Basically I know that I need to use the UIGestureRecogniser function. I haven't programmed much yet but the thing that I feel I need to do now is develop the patterns. So, let's say I have three patterns (basic ones for the purpose of example). 1) ARROW LEFT, ARROW RIGHT. 2) ARROW UP, ARROW DOWN. 3) ARROW UP, ARROW LEFT. I can make the computer recognise what pattern is inputted, but I need a way to have the computer check whether it's similar to the picture. In other words, say pattern 3 pops up and the user does 'ARROW DOWN, ARROW LEFT'. How does the computer realise the input is wrong?

Comment: @arcofclark I have edited my answer, check it and tell me if anything isn't clear.

Comment: Thank you Radwa, you have saved me from weeks of confusion and despair! As I'm relatively new to programming, I would really appreciate it if you could explain stuff like enum and infix funcs. Thanks so much! Will

Comment: Welcome =)...`Enum` is used to define the values that a variable can have, like when you want to represent the traffic lights value that it can be either red,yellow,or green,so it's a variable type not a func. About `infix`, it's used to say that you are going to overload a new infix operator (operator that is used in between two operands), which actually isn't our case here as == isn't a new operator so you can remove it, check [link]( https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/Equatable.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014608-CH17-SW1)

Comment: Here you can read more about operator overloading, infix, postfix, and prefix [link] (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AdvancedOperators.html) .I will remove it from the answer to be less confusing

Comment: Welcome and happy iOS Programming

Comment: Where would I store my enum documents? - a separate file or in the GameViewController? Also, please can you outline what the code would look like for the three patterns that I mentioned in my first comment. Thank you so much.

Comment: 1st question: that would be according to where u need ur enums, if in GameViewController only, then define it there. if other classes needs it then make a separate class where u can define all the common app/game enums. 2nd question what is the problem exactly,Will? as according to http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic we can't just list code here

Comment: Please could you edit your answer using the examples 1, 2, and 3 that I have mentioned in these comments. Thank you so much.